# Chrome's Advanced REST client: Setting a GET request to "Accept: application/json"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using the Chrome app *Advanced REST client*, Version 3.1.1.

When I issue a **GET** request, *Advanced Rest Client* sets the request header with `Accept: */*`.

How can I issue a **GET** request with a request header including `Accept: application/json`?

This option seems to be provided for **POST** requests, but not for **GET** requests.

Comment: This site is not about programming web apps. Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: Hm, "If your question generally covers [...] browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.) [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" ... I'm using (not programming) in my question, no?

Comment: You aren't asking a question about a Web Application, but about a Chrome extension. Unless you're asking about how this works with a specific Web App...?

Comment: Advanced REST client is a Chrome/Chromium extension?

Comment: Does adding `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` change the result?

Comment: @harrymc : Wait a second! You gave me a good idea... trying `Accept: application/json` in the *Raw / Form / Headers* field... sending request. That works! Thank you! ... feel free to post this as an answer! ( here is a usecase: "get JSON from http://hibernate-example.cloudfoundry.com/library/books/"

Comment: It is good that the problem is solved, but the solution is yours to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Accept: application/json` in the *Raw / Form / Headers* field.